# vbscript macros shortening lines of code

Tags: shell, vbscript, macros

so like in C++ where you can turn lines into one word (macro, yes?), is there a way to do this in vbscript?

e.g. instead of

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("Firefox")
```

Can I shorten to something like

```
Set shell = MACRO.Exec("Firefox")
```

If it's just as simple as making a function to do it, can someone give in an example of how to do that whilst adding the ".Exec" to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may shorten the code creating an auxiliary function:

```vb
Dim WshExec

Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec("notepad")

Function WshShell()

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").exec("firefox")
```

Follow the dots. There is an implicit (unnamed) variable, that exists only for the lifetime of the line, holding a `wscript.shell` object. Then you call the `exec` method on that implicit variable.

`Exec` is the wrong command. You need `Run`.

Download help to see the difference  http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe.